# How to select filtered results on a button click from datatable using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have a datatable with some rows, table footer is used to filter the data on datatable. I want to create a select button which can select/deselect only filtered results i.e. select the checkboxes from the first column of filtered results only.
Have used simple HTML here, it looks something like this:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <p>
      <input type="button" id="select" value="Select">
    </p>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="120"></td>
        <td>120</td>
        <td>abc</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="119"></td>
        <td>119</td>
        <td>xyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="textbox"></td>
        <td><input type="textbox"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get the filtered rows by using:

var rows = $(".datatable").dataTable().$('tr', {"filter":"applied"});

then you can iterate each row and apply what you need
check https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/18375/get-all-filtered-rows-across-all-pages
for more info